# Purge and reinstall Ubuntu Desktop

Tags: uninstall, desktop-environments

Ubuntu is unable to start in graphical mode, because some installed package and dependencies (gdk+ ...).
Is it possible to purge it completely and reinstall it ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can do this as follows: (for the default Ubuntu desktop)

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install --reinstall ubuntu-desktop
```

Comment: I am using unity, I reinstalled Ubuntu-desktop after removing it and the package related to, and reinstalling, still unable to access my Gui.